# How we can control the values inside power apps ColumnChart Legend

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-canvas, powerapps-formula, power-platform

I have this SharePoint list which store Total Number of work orders and Total Number of Completed work orders for each month & year & MediumID, as follow:-

[image: johnjohnPter_0-1707328002149.png]

now i want to show the above inside ColumnCart inside a gallery. so this what i did so far:-

I added a gallery with this Items property:-

```
'KPI Dashboard Per Medium'
```

inside the gallery i added a Columnchart as follow with this Items property:-

```
{Date:ThisItem.Month.Value&ThisItem.Year,Total:ThisItem.TotalNumberWorkOrders,Completed:ThisItem.TotalNumberCompletedWorkOrders}
```

[image: johnjohnPter_1-1707328101520.png]

inside the Columnchart i added these advance settings:-

[image: johnjohnPter_2-1707328148858.png]

and i set the number of series to be 2. now i will get these column charts as follow:-

[image]

[image]

but how i can make these changes:-

1. the Legend is currently showing Series1. so how  can show the label of the charts instead (Total & Completed instead)? currently the legend has this settings:-

[image: johnjohnPter_5-1707328323785.png]

so how i can show this legend instead:-

[image: johnjohnPter_1-1707328635913.png]

2. can i show Total and Completed titles under each column? so Total under the solid green column and Completed under the light green column?

Thanks